# Unserialize sometimes returns false

Tags: php, regex, serialization

I have this function in my application:

```
public function direct($theTree)
{
    $aTreeRoot = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!se', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $theTree);
    return unserialize($aTreeRoot);
}
```

It should never return false but in the error logs the error keep occuring which says it returned false.

However, I cannot replicate the error in my application. I'm trying to every possible way but it always works.

Is there something wrong with the function?

The `$theTree` comes from session.

*Edit:* The regex is there because: [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) - Search for my regex there in the comments. It's supposed to solve a problem.

Comment: Is this `preg_replacing` really necessary? The example this Igor character gives that prompted this workaround is a completely invalid serialized string to begin with. I'm not aware of any bugs that would necessitate this. If your string was serialized with `serialize` and wasn't modified, it should `unserialize` just fine. Did you come across this problem yourself, or did you just put it in because "it's supposed to solve *a* problem"?

Comment: @deceze: Yes, without that regex the unserialize does not work. I am putting a complicated object into session serialized and without the regex there are problems unserializing it. The regex solves that problem but still it seems unserialize sometimes returns false.

Comment: Triple check that your serialized string does not pick up any extra characters on the way somewhere, changes encoding etc. Can you give an example that fails?

Comment: I am converting string from Windows-1250 to UTF-8 after serializing. Not sure if that is significiant.

Comment: @deceze I don't have any example right now. I will update my error hadler to save the string in case of future errors like this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but changing the encoding might have an impact, since the length of strings change (if measured in bytes, not 100% sure what a serialized string stores the length as).

Comment: @deceze Yes. That's what is mentioned in the comments a lot people seem to have problems with UTF-8 strings. Igor's fix is supposed to solve this.

Comment: @deceze I will try saving it nativly, as Windows-1250 and using iconv only when printing its contents with echo. Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: and window-1250 is not a direct subset of UTF-8. some character might miss in encoding. So, try with simple characters first.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I have faced similar kind of issue earlier. I show u how i have solved it.

After you serialize data, apply base64_encode()
e.g

```
$txt = base64_encode(serialize($txt));
```

And when you unserialize it

e.g.

```
 $txt = unserialize(base64_decode($txt));
```

Try this . Hope work for u as well. Good luck

Comment: what is this sorcery about? It actually works... But would be nice to understand!

Comment: This is why I never should use "serialize" "unserialize".  If it doesn't do what you'd expect it to do, then why use it.  JSON encode decode works fine.

Comment: @Preexo base64 encodes the data as an ascii string, bypassing charset issues from your db to your server script, and if you're scraping data from the net then: from the source, to the db, back to your script.  Things can go wrong in translation.  Obviously `serialize` `unserialize` doesn't always encode to decode itself so people have problems with it.  If you base64 it, you loose looking at the data directly when viewing raw entries from the db.

Answer (score 1):

I got some random behaviour on my code, but I think I found out why. I was using UTF-8 charset, and in my production server, it seems to produce these issues.
Try this:

```
$txt = unserialize(utf8_encode($aTreeRoot));
```

Worked for me, hope it will for you too

Answer (score 0):

I believe escaping the data you're serializing would also work as an alternative to base64.

```
$data = serialize($results);
$encoded = htmlentities($data);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="'.$encoded.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems.  Turns out the column in the DB that was storing the serialized array had a collation of: `latin1_swedish_ci`

I changed the collation of the serialized data column to: `utf8_bin` and re-svaed the data and voila - problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the string to unserialize needed to be trimmed! The error message was not helpful in this case and I stumbled upon the solution by looking at some other code.

```
$unserialized = unserialize(trim($serialized));
```